# How can I get English username on French Localized Windows?

Tags: windows, localization, operating-system

I am using French Localized Windows Operating system.

I am using **GetUserName**() Windows API to get current logged in username for the process.

On French Windows it returns "**Système**" instead of "**System**" for the Service process. Because of this our System Software failing in a specific scenario.

Is there any way to get English UserName on French Windows ?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault. But no, there isn't, because the user was actually named Système during installation, and the only thing you can do about it is rename the user. Which might or might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be mixing up the accounts now, but I think you should be comparing using the SIDs rather than the usernames. For example, the `Local System` account always have SID `S-1-5-18`.

You can find a list of standard SIDs here: [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330)

And if you need to go from account name to SID you can use the [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379159%28VS.85%29.aspx) API (maybe easier ways of doing it, but that was the first one I could think off).

Comment: according to MSDN on `LocalSystem` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190(VS.85).aspx ) even though the user name is localized, you *should* be able to use .\LocalSystem as an account name, just not for `LookupAccountName` since Local System isn't recognized by the security subsystem

Comment: @Yoni: Though I think the problem is that he's not "using" it, but rather is trying to compare it against a string. But I forgot that you can't "look up" `Local System`.